# SSL Certificate Installation for site having domain registered on another server

Tags: ssl, server, installation, csr

I have registered domain on one server and pointed to justhost server space. I have purchased ssl certificate from thirdparty. Where I have to add the certificate I got , on domain server or justhost server which I have uploaded files?

Comment: The cert needs to be installed on the server where the domain for which you purchased it is.

Comment: But there is no option for ssl installation on domain server(hexonet). ssl is showing as active on the domain server. But redirection not working.

Comment: I got error: "None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (domain.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors."

Comment: You are offtopic here, your problem has nothing to do with programming. Did you start by trying to ask the provider you pay for a service, so that they can help you? You obfuscated things so much that it is impossible to give you relevant help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand your setup but where the certificate lives is ultimately not relevant. What really matters is what is in the Common Name (CN) field of the certificate and/or what is in the Subject Alternative Names (SAN) extension. [And the rule is simple](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1): if the user enters https://example.com/this/that/whatever to get to your site then your certificate must contain `example.com` in the CN component of the subject and/or the SAN extension.

Comment: I contacted server technical support team they helped me to install it. Thanks.